# One Javascript code stops firing when another is triggered

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dropdown

My coworker and I are working on this page: https://secure.centerforinquiry.net/galaxy-level-membership-michigan.

Because Blackbaud Netcommunity doesn't let us choose a dropdown display for the CFI Branch affiliation option, we thought we could write our own dropdown and sync it up with the checkboxes, then hide the checkboxes with CSS. (We have unhid the unsightly checkboxes for purposes of troubleshooting)

We got that part working but there is another piece of Javascript on that page that syncs up the One-time vs Recurring payment options. Whenever someone picks recurring payment and then adjusts the branch dropdown, the checkboxes no longer respond. The javascript for the dropdown/checkbox sync also doesn't work if the dropdown is adjusted after submitting the form with errors.

How can we restart this javascript file in these situations?

Comment: This form is too complicated to understand how to work with it.

Comment: Hey Andy, 

Definitely! Unfortunately that donation form is generated by NetCommunity so I can't do much about that.

To be clearer on what I need help with, this file:
https://www.centerforinquiry.net/js/dropdown-checker.js
no longer works when this other javascript file is triggered:
https://www.centerforinquiry.net/js/membership-switcher.js

The dropdown javascript also stops working when the form is submitted and has errors.

Comment: to be on the same page: I select Recurring Payment and then pick Austing in the Branch dropdown then CFI Austin is not checked, right?